# Changing the text of clabel in Matplotlib

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I would like to specify the text of my contour label (instead of the value of the contour I want to put a text)
I've tried:

```
CS = contour(X, Y, Z, [0.5], linewidths=1, colors='k')
plt.clabel(CS, fontsize=10, inline=1, text=r'$\alpha=0$')
```

but it doesn't work.
Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
plt.clabel(CS, fontsize=10, inline=1, fmt=r'$\alpha=0$')
```